# Disable google analytics when using jquery/jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, jstree

I'm building a jstree tree viewer which ultimately will be behind a firewall and I noticed that my script is calling ga.js from an anonymous function in my top level script.

So how do I disable this an an elegant way without digging through all the JavaScript? I don't think the requests will be satisfied when requested, but it will keep asking for it every time the page loads, which is a nuisance.

This is my code, other than the jquery 1.10, jquery cookie and jtree pre 1.0 boilerplate.

```
    $("#myTree")
    .jstree({   
            "json_data" : {
               "ajax" : {
                  "type" : "GET", 
                  "url" : "xxxxxxx.cgi",
                  "data" : function (n) {  return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 }; },
                  "success": function (new_data) { return new_data; }
                  "progressive_render" : true
                },
            },
            "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "checkbox"],
     });
```

Comment: possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539053/prevent-my-data-from-affecting-google-analytics/17539405#17539405

Comment: can you post the code that has the `ga.js` in it?

Comment: I don't see any "ga.js" in what you posted.  Maybe you mean there is a <script> from google in the HTML.  If so, you could just remove that script tag from the HTML, and then the tracking code won't load.

Comment: okay false alarm. it looks to be included as one of our standard includes. I wasn't expecting that

Answer (score 1):

Just do a search for `ga.js` and remove the call manually.  You can comment it out, etc.  Once JavaScript is loaded, it will remain in memory, even removing from it from the DOM, will not remove it from memory.  I found this our recently.  So don't let it load into memory is my point.